# Simple sound pause/play toggle button

Tags: flash, audio, toggle, actionscript-2, playback

I have a website with a simple sound pause/play toggle button. I want to recreate this flash button to change a few things around there (the current button I got from someone else). I am a novice to flash (and programming of any kind in general).

Here is the functionality that I need:

1. The website loads and music starts playing automatically
2. Upon clicking the music icon, it pauses
3. Upon clicking the music icon again, it resumes playing

The icon has no animation. It is just a static icon that I would import from PS (.png).

That simple!

I only have access to AS2.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers,
Ashish

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2uXokbwUWA